# Cloud kit: how to get public database subscription notification from your group of contacts only

Tags: cloudkit, cksubscription

I have CKRecord for Location details in the public database. I want to create a subscription for a CKrecord with location details, stored in the public database. I want to set subscription so I get notification from those that are in my contacts group only. The subscription notification on Location CKrecord notifies me on all users which takes more time to sort through and I want to avoid this.

How can I set the subscription?

Comment: It depends a little on how your data is structured. Does your `Location` record type have a `CKReference` field pointing to your `Contact` record type?

Comment: When I mean Contacts I mean my iphone contacts. All my iphone contacts may not be app users.  If I create a CKRecordContact to represent my contacts and point it to location, I still have to pull down all the CKRecordContact's  of all iphone users and then search for my contacts and then pull locations. How can I minimize the search to my iphone contacts only? I hope I have explained clearly

Comment: It seems to me that you are going in the wrong direction. You should first pull the contacts from your phone, and then perform a `CKQuery` with an `NSPredicate` that limits the search to the contacts on your phone. You will then fetch only the `CKRecord`s you need.

Comment: I am able to pull contacts. Now how do I limit my search only for my contacts from cloud. What should be my NSPredicate and CKQuery look like? Can you please share that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `Location` recordType has some kind of `userEmail` field on it, you can query for those records like this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userEmail = %@", argumentArray: ["name@example.com"])
  
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Location", predicate: predicate)
let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
  
var records = [CKRecord]()
operation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
  records.append(record)
}

operation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in
  print("Done.")
  print(records)
}

CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.yourContainer").publicCloudDatabase.add(operation)
```

Comment: Ok then, I can pass an array of emails of my contacts to get all location records. But how can I minimize my contacts to only those who have installed the app? Is there a way to find out who has installed the app and then send only those contact's emails to get the records.

Comment: No, you would have to query with all the emails of all your contacts. When the records come back from the `CKQuery`, you will then know who has the app installed. The source of truth is CloudKit. Your contacts don't store any information about who has installed your app.

Comment: Ok, so If the user's record comes back then the user has app installed, otherwise take it as a no?

Comment: Yeah, your `Users` table in the Public database has a unique `recordName` for every use that has installed your app. That's how you know who installed it and started interacting with CloudKit.

Comment: Ok. I am still in development and no user has installed the app. So how should I set it up for testing across users? If I run the app on a different phone with different Apple ID will it create the record in the users table of public database?